# appium not getting elements inside RecyclerView

Tags: automated-tests, appium, appium-android, appium-desktop

I need to fetch each FrameLayot div value inside the RecyclerView.

[AS Shown in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfyKg.jpg)

I used the code

```
List<WebElement> ulElement = driver.findElements(By.id("pager"));

int sz = ulElement.size();

System.out.println(sz);
```

But getting result as 1 instead of 9

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the result as 9 you should use the following code:

```
List<WebElement> ulElement = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView[@index='0']/give_the_class_name_of_framelayout"));

int sz = ulElement.size();

System.out.println(sz);
```

You have to give such value to the locator, so that it will return 9 matching elements. I hope this helps you out.

Comment: Thanks for your support

Answer (score 0):

I got the Result by split the view

```
WebElement parentElement  = driver.findElement(By.id("com.mathrubhumi.silverbullet:id/mlist"));
List<WebElement> childElement = parentElement.findElements(By.id("com.mathrubhumi.silverbullet:id/rootview"));
System.out.println(celement.size());
```